Continuum among converging sum of reciprocals of natural numbers sandwiched between consecutive terms
Define $u:=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}\approx 0.6.\ $ Given $x\in \left[ u ,\ 1 \right]$, is there a (strictly increasing) sequence of positive integers $\left( a_{n} \right)_{n=1}^{\infty},$ with $2^n\leq a_{n}\leq 2^{n+1}-1\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N},$ such that $ x =\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n}$?
I guess we have to use that $\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ along with the greedy algorithm, but I am not immediately putting the pieces of the puzzle together.

My intuition is that a careful greedy-ish algorithm will suffice, for a much broader class of problems. I've made this answer Community wiki in case anyone wants to flesh out this idea (assuming it's correct).
Let $s_1<b_1<s_2<b_2<s_3<b_3<\cdots$ be a sequence of integers. For each $n\ge1$, define
$$
\beta_n = \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac1{b_k} \quad\text{and}\quad \sigma_n = \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac1{s_k};
$$
assume that the sequences $(s_k)$ and $(b_k)$ are chosen so that one (and thus all) of these series converge.
I believe: for any $\alpha\in[\beta_1,\sigma_1]$, there exists a sequence $(a_k)$ of positive integers, with $s_k \le a_k \le b_k$ for all $k\ge1$, such that $\alpha = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/a_k$.
Furthmore, I believe that the following algorithm works: once $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ have been chosen, choose $a_n$ to be any integer in $[s_n,b_n]$ such that
$$
\alpha-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{a_n} \in [\beta_{n+1},\sigma_{n+1}].
$$
The challenge is proving that such an $a_n$ always exists; if they do, the assertion follows immediately.

I think this is not true: all numbers we can get are in $\bigcup\limits_{a_1=s_1}^{b_1} [1/a_1 + \beta_2, 1/a_1 + \sigma_2]$. If, for example, $s_1 = 1$, $b_1 = 2$, $s_{n+1} = 2^{-100n}$, we get $\beta_2, \sigma_2 < 1/10$, and thus it's impossible to get, for example, $\alpha = 2/3$. We need the sequence to grow not too fast.
